# effect on video using GPU image Framework but completion block of movie writer is never called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

```
self.movie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"merge_video" ofType:@"mp4"]]];

self.sketchFilter = [[GPUImageSketchFilter alloc]init];

[self.movie addTarget:self.sketchFilter];

self.movie.runBenchmark = YES;

self.movie.playAtActualSpeed = NO;

NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/MyMovie.m4v"];

unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];

self.writer = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc]initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(320, 320)];

[self.sketchFilter addTarget:self.writer];

[self.writer setShouldPassthroughAudio:YES];

[self.movie setAudioEncodingTarget: self.writer];

__weak GPUImageMovieWriter *weakSelf = writer;

[self.movie enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter: weakSelf];

[ weakSelf startRecording];

[self.movie startProcessing];

[weakSelf setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Effecting Completed Succefully");
    [self.sketchFilter removeTarget:weakSelf];
    [weakSelf finishRecording];
}];
```

Comment: Format this appropriately!

Comment: This isn't a code review site. Please explain what you have tried and what is happening.

Comment: @BaummitAugen  here i am applying effect on video and saving file to document directory but video file created with size 0 byte

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where you define the `writer` instance variable, but I bet you created that as an instance variable and then created a `writer` property which is instead backed by a generated `_writer` variable.

This means that `writer` is nil in the above and your movie never even starts processing. Use `self.writer` instead.